# Resources similar to Nicos Weg for Finnish

Tags: resource-request, multiple-languages, electronic-resources, finnish

While learning German, I've found Nicos Weg to be a good resource alongside, and sometimes even more useful than, Duolingo. It's a course provided by the German public international broadcaster Deutsche Welle. It takes the form of short (1-3 mins) videos following a character, followed by excercises.

I've seen similar resources for French, but none for Finnish. Are there similar resources for it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please split up this question into one for Finnish and one for Korean? We like to keep our questions focused.

Comment: I've edited this question to focus on Finnish and posted one for Korean (https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/resources-similar-to-nicos-weg-for-korean). Does that work?

Comment: Yle has material available, but I have not looked into them or Nicos weg: https://yle.fi/aihe/artikkeli/2015/12/15/suomi-finnish

Comment: Yes, that's excellent. Thanks!