# Resources similar to Nicos Weg for Korean

Tags: resource-request, multiple-languages, electronic-resources, korean

While learning German, I've found Nicos Weg to be a good resource alongside, and sometimes even more useful than, Duolingo. It's a course provided by the German public international broadcaster Deutsche Welle. It takes the form of short (1-3 mins) videos following a character, followed by excercises.

I've seen similar resources for French, but none for Korean. Are there similar resources for it?